# How to subclass DefaultTableModel and change its dataVector

Tags: java, swing

I want to extend the DefaultTableModel and change its dataVector.
I want to make the dataVector to show only specific fields of DataHolder in the column:

```
 public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    /**
     * The data vector
     */
    private Vector<DataHolder>   dataVector_;

    //overridden method to add row in the table model
    public void addRow(DataHolder rowData) {
        insertRow(getRowCount(), rowData);
    }

    public void insertRow(int row, DataHolder rowData) {
            dataVector_.insertElementAt(rowData, row);
            fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
        }

    ...} //end of MyTableModel



   class DataHolder{
     private int age;
     private int year;
     private int month;
     private int day;
    }
```

How can i display specific DataHolder fields in my jtable? My table has 3 columns for month, day, and year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the `getValueAt(...)` method:

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    DataHolder data = dataVector_.get(row);
    switch(column) {
        case 0: return data.month;
        case 1: return data.day;
        case 2: return data.year;
        default: return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this method called by the table renderer during update of table data especially when fireTableRowsInserted is called?

Comment: This method is allways called, when the table changed fireTable...() and when the table is repainted.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a custom model for this. The DefaultTableModel is not the best place to start.

Generally you would extend AbstractTableModel and use an ArrayList to store your DataHolder Objects. Then you need to implement the other methods of the TableModel interface. The Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) shows you the basics of how to do this.

Or you can use the [Bean Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/) which does all the work for you.

Comment: Thanks :) BeanTableModel gonna be so much helpful. Just what I was about to create.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change this in the Table Model or the Table View? If you are using a JTable for the view, might I suggest working with the [TableColumnModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html) which is accessible via the [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getColumnModel%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I want to change it in the table model. All I want to know is what method to use to specify to the model what to display from my DataHolder.

Comment: There is more than one method you need to change, that is why you need to write a completely new TableModel. The code you posted means nothing and is completely wrong. You can't just change the data vector and forget about the header vector. All methods in the model work together. Create a proper TableModel and it will be easier to understand and use.